# Java factory inheritance with generic interface implementation

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, factory

I would like to have a factory that inherits another one with both factories implementing same generic interface with different type that inherits one another:

```
class FactoryA implements FactoryI<A> {
    // common code
    ...
    A get() {
        return new A();
    }
}

class FactoryB extends FactoryA implements FactoryI<B> {
    B get() {
        return new B();
    }
}

class B extends A {
}

FactoryI<T> {
    T get()
}
```

But this gives me following compilation error:

```
'FactoryI' cannot be inherited with different type arguments: 'A' and 'B'
```

My first version did not have FactoryB inheriting from FactoryA and this was working fine.
But it turns out that there is now common code between both factories that I want to reuse.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `FactoryA` generic as well. This way a subclass can return a different subclass of `A`

```
class FactoryA<T extends A> implements FactoryI<T> {
    // common code
    public T get() {
        return (T) new A();
    }
}

class FactoryB extends FactoryA<B> {
    public B get() {
        return new B();
    }
}

class A {

}

class B extends A {
}

interface FactoryI<T> {
    T get();
}
```

Comment: The unchecked type cast should be alarming to you. You can now write `FactoryA<B> f = new FactoryA<>();` without getting an error. This instantiation will not even raise a warning, as the problematic code that caused a warning is inside the `get()` method.

Comment: @Holger there is the potential to misuse this pattern however, the first time you test it if you have abused it will blow up. This does require the callee to get it right but the caller doesn't need to know anything special.

Comment: The problem is that it will *not* blow up at `FactoryA<B> f = new FactoryA<>();`, it’s not even guaranteed to blow up at the much later call of `get()`, as that call might be inside generic code as well. Whether the place where it blows up has an obvious connection to the instantiation of `FactoryA`, is unpredictable. And well, even if it has, the instantiation is not wrong. It’s the implementation of `FactoryA` that is.

Comment: You can easily make a clean solution, `class FactoryA { /* common code */ public A get() { return new A(); } public static final FactoryI<A> FACTORY_A = new FactoryA()::get; }` and `class FactoryB extends FactoryA { @Override public B get() { return new B(); } public static final FactoryI<B> FACTORY_B = new FactoryB()::get; }`